# when uploading a file With some details , they are freating 2 rows in SQL DB

Tags: c#, sql

After inserting data & file upload with a single save button, 2 rows are created in DB. I want to make both rows into one row. please suggest. The details are attached.[Application GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic2SU.jpg)

[Design & Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TY61.jpg)

```cs
{
  con.Open ();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("spStockInWard", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Insert");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@SerialNumber", textBox1.Text.Trim ());
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@AssetType", comboBox1.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@AssetMake", comboBox2.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@AssetModel", textBox2.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@HDDSize", comboBox5.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@RAMSize", comboBox6.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@MonitorType", comboBox7.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@StockReceivedDate", textBox3.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@InvoiceDate", textBox4.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@InvoiceNumber", textBox5.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@AssetStatus", comboBox3.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@WorkingStatus", comboBox4.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Remarks", textBox6.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.Add ("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
  cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
  string message = (string) cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;
  MessageBox.Show (message.ToString (), "Userinfo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
  con.Close ();
} else
{
  MessageBox.Show ("Please Fill All Details!");
}
try {
  string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName (openFileDialog1.FileName);
  if (filename == null) {
    MessageBox.Show ("Please select a valid document.");
  } else {

    con.Open ();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("insert into tblStockInWard (document) values('D:\\AMS-Docs\\StockInWard\\" + filename + "')", con);
    string path = Application.StartupPath.Substring (0, (Application.StartupPath.Length - 50));
    System.IO.File.Copy (openFileDialog1.FileName, @"D:\\AMS-Docs\\StockInWard\\" + filename);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    con.Close ();
    MessageBox.Show ("Document uploaded.");
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  MessageBox.Show (ex.Message);
}
```

these all are my codes.

Comment: Well - first you insert a row with the details - then you insert another row with the file - of course you end up with **2 rows** for each insert operation! You need to **either** (1) determine the file based info **before** inserting the first row and include that information in the `INSERT` - or then (2) you need to **UPDATE** (instead of `INSERT`) the row you just inserted with the file based information !

Comment: So are you saying you've already ruined the production database and filled it with double rows, and now need help fixing it.. or are you saying you need help fixing this code so it only inserts one row? (which is easy: make sure your code only contains one `ExecuteNonQuery` rather than two)

Comment: ps; "these are all my codes" - not quite true; you have a stored procedure that actually does the insert in one case and you didn't provide the code for it

Comment: @CaiusJard , i want to make one row with file atachment path also.

Comment: @marc_s , i tried to update statement but it's not updatong row "update tblStockInWard set document = 'D:\\AMS-Docs\\StockInWard\\" + filename + "' where SerialNumber = 'textBox1.Text' "

Comment: You know that parameterizing thing you do to call your stored procedure? You should do that for your normal sql too. Solves all manner of problems that one. http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment - you need to **insert** your details first, and then you need to **UPDATE** that row you just inserted with the remaining info (or even simpler - why can't you just set the value of the `document` column in the initial `INSERT`, too??).

Also: I'd **strongly** recommend to (a) stay away from using `.AddWithValue()`, and also use the **appropriate** data types for the parameters - since you haven't shown us your stored procedure, I can only *guess* what those might be - adapt as needed.

```
// get the "serial no" - assuming this is the **primary key** for the table
string serialNo = textBox1.Text.Trim();

// create your INSERT stored procedure call
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spStockInWard", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// add parameters with the ".Add()" method, also specifying the datatype used    
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = serialNo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetMake", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetModel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HDDSize", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RAMSize", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitorType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox7.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockReceivedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox5.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssetStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkingStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox4.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = textBox6.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

// open connection, insert details
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;

MessageBox.Show(message.ToString(), "Userinfo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

// second step - **UPDATE** the newly inserted row with your file info
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

if (filename == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid document.");
    con.Close();
}
else
{
    // define the UPDATE statement against the same row as inserted above       
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblStockInWard SET document = @document WHERE SerialNumber = @SerialNo";
    
    // re-use "serial no" from above
    cnd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = serialNo;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@document", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = "D:\\AMS-Docs\\StockInWard\\" + filename;
    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Document uploaded.");
}
```

Comment: I think the AddWithValue thing could do with a bit more qualification; it's only something that should really be avoided in parameterized SQL Server WHERE clauses. It's much less of a problem (to the extent I'd say no problem) with stored procedures, or other databases (MySQL say "use AddWithValue") so I think a blanket "don't use AddWithValue" is excessive. I say "use AddWithValue, 'cos at least then SQL is parameterized, and learn the few scenarios under which to avoid it if you want to level-up your coding or it is causing a definite performance problem"